# Can we pass a hostname/IP address as a query string in a GET request in REST API

Tags: security, request

If I have to pass a hostname or a IP address as part of a GET request, is it okay to do it as a query parameter? Will there be any security risks?
The response of the GET request will depend on the input IP address. So passing the IP address as payload for a GET request is not probably a good design (Reference: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body))

Eg: http://localhost:3000/1/192.167.1.2/

Comment: Depending on what will happen to that IP address later (how it will be used), it may create an open redirect or an SSRF vulnerability. If you're sure it does not, then it's ok, but the point in general is, input must not be trusted.

Comment: @GaborLengyel, what would you suggest is the safest way to input a IP address as part of the request? My usecase is to use the input hostname/IP address to perform a RPC using it.

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot be answered here. Passing the IP address is one thing, the url can be ok, but how you validate and use it is the key. This is way broader than a comment or an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you from specifying a Host/IP in the path or query portions of the url, if it is actually an input value that the server will use in a data query.

But, if you are trying to tailor the server to host multiple sites on a single IP and differentiate them by host names, then use the HTTP `Host` header instead.

Comment: The use case is to use the input hostname/IP address to perform a RPC using it. So I don't think HTTP Host header will be helpful?

Comment: Then I would suggest using the actual query string, eg: `http://localhost:3000/1/?ip=192.167.1.2`